# Jquery mobile external page still with parent page formatting

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I have a jquery mobile page with a list menu :

```
  <div data-role="content">
    <div class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all">
        <div class="ui-corner-all custom-corners">
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li><a href="historique.php" data-transition="slide" ><img src="../favicon.jpg" alt="fav" class="ui-li-icon" data-prefetch>Historique</a></li>
                <li><a href="tarifs.php" data-transition="slide" ><img src="../favicon.jpg" alt="fav" class="ui-li-icon" data-prefetch>Tarifs détaillés</a></li>
                <li><a href="galerie.php"><img src="../favicon.jpg" alt="fav" class="ui-li-icon" rel="external" target="_blank">Galerie</a></li>

            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

On the 3rd item I am trying to load a pahe that does not have any jquery mobile formatting in it, just plain html, but when you click on the link the browser keeps the index's layout and the page looks like nothing.

However, if you reload that page, the forlatting comes back to what it should be.

Has anyone an idea ?

Comment: Plain `rel="external"` won't do the trick I believe, but `data-rel="external"` should work as you expect.

Comment: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/navigation-linking-pages/ : "Links that point to other domains or that have rel="external", data-ajax="false" or target attributes will not be loaded with Ajax"

Comment: Yes, and this is indeed the problem : even with rel="external" and/or data-ajax="false" it is still loaded with ajax, with a loading image etc..